# Express JS Authorization Verify User Roles & Permissions

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, authorization, middleware

I'm trying to add JWT Authentication & Authorization to my express server. In my Initial implementation I've worked to verify the roles however, I want add on top of it. The basic functionality I want to add is to give the admin users the ability add custom roles and add/edit permissions for each role (from a set list of permissions). My DB looks something like this:

```
model Role {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title         String?
  User          User[]
  permissions   RolePermissions[]
  @@map("roles")
}

model Permissions {
  id                    Int                     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title                 String
  roles   RolePermissions[]
}

model RolePermissions {
  id                    Int                     @id @default(autoincrement())
  roleId                Int                     
  permissionId          Int                     
  role                  Role                    @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  permission            Permissions              @relation(fields: [permissionId], references: [id])
}
```

Here is middleware to verify roles:

```
const verifyRoles = (...allowedRoles) => {
    return (req,res,next) =>{
        if(!req?.roles){
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }
        const roles = [...allowedRoles];
        console.log(roles,req.roles)
        const result = req.roles.map(role=> roles.includes(role)).find(val=>val === true);
        if(!result){
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

Now, I'm stuck at the authorization part. Almost all the examples I've found are dealing with fixed permissions for a role so they are only verifying the role on each request and not the permissions. In regards to this I've a couple of Implementations in mind:

1. In the middeware to verify roles, I can fetch the permissions for
   each of the roles assigned to the user and verify the needed
   permission from that, this can make the overall request pretty slow.
2. Instead of adding the user's roles to the jwt, adding the
   permissions to the jwt. However the permissions list can be quite
   extensive.

I'm curios as to what is the best way to go about this. Any ideas or resources you can share are much appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**
I have opted for saving user permissions on the jwt accesToken. However this brought forward another concern. If a user is already logged in, and someone (an admin) changes their role or edits a role that they have, their jwt will still have the old permissions till they login again. Not sure how to go about this at the moment.

Additionaly, I would also like to hide buttons, pages and menu items on the front-end based on the users permissions, should I save these in the users session on login or fetch these on the frontend in a separate api call each time?